# Is it appropriate to use an emoticon in reminder email to a potential employer?

Tags: email, jobs

A potential employer promised me a response but hasn't sent one yet, and I'd like to follow up by email.  It's a potential job opportunity, and it'd be detrimental to sound too hasty or pushy.

I was thinking of something like:

> Good morning,
>
> I was wondering if you had a chance to consider my resume.
>
> I've also attached my cover letter with this email :)
>
> Please let me know if there's anything else required from my end.
>
> Kind regards,

I know it's not necessary, but I'm wondering how functional the smiley would be. I'm just trying to make this sound as friendly and neutral as possible and not too pushy.

Does using a smiley in this context help or hurt, or does it not matter?

Comment: Entirely my opinion, but smilies tend to connotate a casual atmosphere, as opposed to a professional one. With some jobs this might be good (depending on the atmosphere of the job), but with most, I would definitely leave the smilie out.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.  I've made some edits to your question -- (a) formatting, and (b) to focus on the emoticon (smiley) that seems to be the key part of your question.  You can see what I changed by clicking on the "edited" link above my user name below your post.  If I've misunderstood anything, you can [edit] to make further changes.  Thanks for bringing your question here.

Answer (score 4):

I was a division manager of a public company, at one point in my life (for four years). Not all managers are the same, But for me: Skip the emoji, just tell the truth and ask for a decision.

> Dear Sir,
>
> We discussed a job last xxxx and I left my resume with you.
>
> I know you were in the middle of renovations, So there would be some delay. I am hoping you have had a chance since then to review my resume, and can let me know if I am a good fit, or if I should pursue other opportunities. I am still interested in joining the team.
>
> Thanks in advance for your attention,
>
> legoMyEgo

Answer (score 3):

emoting is not recommended unless you are describing your excitement for the prospect. It's considered respectful to follow up after a week and let them know you are still interested. Good job seekers don't stop until they get a "no".

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a "good" job seeker? Speaking as someone who read résumés and helped in a hiring process, there is a *world* of difference between "a respectful follow-up one week later" and "repeated contact until the person gets a clear No."

Comment: Good employers want to hire good job seekers because the effort they put in to finding a job represents the effort they should put in while on the job. Would you prefer to hire someone who follows up regularly and politely, or someone who sits back and expects the employer to take the initiative? There is no difference between the two when done correctly. You can be polite once a week for a year. The only employers who would take offense to that are the type of employers you won't want to work for anyway.

Comment: "Respectful follow-up once a week" is a perfectly reasonable definition, thank you.